# MySQL looking for a nice index

Tags: mysql, sql, select, indexing

I have this table (simplified version)

```
create table completions (
  id int(11) not null auto_increment,
  completed_at datetime default null,
  is_mongo_synced tinyint(1) default '0',
  primary key (id),
  key index_completions_on_completed_at_and_is_mongo_synced_and_id (completed_at,is_mongo_synced,id),
) engine=innodb auto_increment=4785424 default charset=utf8 collate=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Size:

```
select count(*) from completions; -- => 4817574
```

Now I try to execute this query:

```
select completions.* 
from completions  
where 
  (completed_at is not null) 
  and completions.is_mongo_synced = 0 
  order by completions.id asc limit 10;
```

And it takes **9mins**.

I see there is not any index used, the `explain extend` returns this:

```
id: 1 
select_type: SIMPLE
table: completions 
type: index 
possible_keys: index_completions_on_completed_at_and_is_mongo_synced_and_id  
key: PRIMARY 
key_len: 4 
ref: NULL  
rows: 20  
filtered: 11616415.00 
Extra: Using where
```

If I force the index:

```
select completions.* 
from completions  
force index(index_completions_on_completed_at_and_is_mongo_synced_and_id)
where 
  (completed_at is not null) 
  and completions.is_mongo_synced = 0 
  order by completions.id asc limit 10;
```

It takes **1,22s**, which is much better. The `explain extend` returns:

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: completions
type: range
possible_keys: index_completions_on_completed_at_and_is_mongo_synced_and_id
key: index_completions_on_completed_at_and_is_mongo_synced_and_id
key_len: 6
ref: null
rows: 2323334
filtered: 100
Extra: Using index condition; Using filesort
```

Now if I narrow the query by `completions.id` like:

```
select completions.* 
from completions  
force index(index_completions_on_completed_at_and_is_mongo_synced_and_id)
where 
  (completed_at is not null) 
  and completions.is_mongo_synced = 0 
  and completions.id > 2000000
  order by completions.id asc limit 10;
```

It takes **1,31s**, still good. The `explain extend` returns:

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: completions
type: range
possible_keys: index_completions_on_completed_at_and_is_mongo_synced_and_id
key: index_completions_on_completed_at_and_is_mongo_synced_and_id
key_len: 6
ref: null
rows: 2323407
filtered: 100
Extra: Using index condition; Using filesort
```

The point is that if for the last query I don't force the index:

```
select completions.* 
from completions  
where 
  (completed_at is not null) 
  and completions.is_mongo_synced = 0 
  and completions.id > 2000000
  order by completions.id asc limit 10;
```

It takes **85ms**, check that it is **ms** and not **s**. The `explain extend` returns:

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: completions
type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARYindex_completions_on_completed_at_and_is_mongo_synced_and_id
key: PRIMARY
key_len: 4
ref: null
rows: 2323451
filtered: 100
Extra: Using where
```

Not only this is making me nuts but also the fact that the performance of the last query is highly affected for small changes in the number of the filter:

```
select completions.* 
from completions  
where 
  (completed_at is not null) 
  and completions.is_mongo_synced = 0 
  and completions.id > 1600000
  order by completions.id asc limit 10;
```

It takes **13s**

Things I don't understand:

1. Why this the below query A is faster than query B when query B suppose to use a more precise index:
   c

Query A:

```
select completions.* 
from completions  
where 
  (completed_at is not null) 
  and completions.is_mongo_synced = 0 
  and completions.id > 2000000
  order by completions.id asc limit 10;
```

**85ms**

Query B:

```
select completions.* 
from completions  
force index(index_completions_on_completed_at_and_is_mongo_synced_and_id)
where 
  (completed_at is not null) 
  and completions.is_mongo_synced = 0 
  and completions.id > 2000000
  order by completions.id asc limit 10;
```

**1,31s**

### 2. Why such a difference in performan among the below queries:

Query A:

```
select completions.* 
from completions  
where 
  (completed_at is not null) 
  and completions.is_mongo_synced = 0 
  and completions.id > 2000000
  order by completions.id asc limit 10;
```

**85ms**

Query B:

```
select completions.* 
from completions  
where 
  (completed_at is not null) 
  and completions.is_mongo_synced = 0 
  and completions.id > 1600000
  order by completions.id asc limit 10;
```

**13s**

### 3. Why MySQL is not using automatically the index for the below query:

Index:

```
key index_completions_on_completed_at_and_is_mongo_synced_and_id (completed_at,is_mongo_synced,id),
```

Query:

```
select completions.* 
from completions  
force index(index_completions_on_completed_at_and_is_mongo_synced_and_id)
where 
  (completed_at is not null) 
  and completions.is_mongo_synced = 0 
  and completions.id > 2000000
  order by completions.id asc limit 10;
```

#### Update

Some more data requested in the comments

Num of rows based on `is_mongo_synced` values

```
 select
     completions.is_mongo_synced,
     count(*)
 from completions
 group by completions.is_mongo_synced;
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "is_mongo_synced":0,
    "count(*)":2731921
  },
  {
    "is_mongo_synced":1,
    "count(*)":2087869
  }
]
```

Queries without `order by`

```
select completions.* 
from completions  
where 
  (completed_at is not null) 
  and completions.is_mongo_synced = 0 
  and completions.id > 2000000
  limit 10;
```

**544ms**

```
select completions.* 
from completions  
force index(index_completions_on_completed_at_and_is_mongo_synced_and_id)
where 
  (completed_at is not null) 
  and completions.is_mongo_synced = 0 
  and completions.id > 2000000
  limit 10;
```

**314ms**

But, anyhow, I need the order because I'm scanning the table batch by batch.

Comment: Query optimizers can be frustratingly obtuse at times. :)

Comment: What are the possible values for is_mongo_synced field? (my guess: 0 and 1) Can you pls post a count of records by is_mongo_synced values? If you are filtering and ordering based on is_mongo_synced and id fields, then why don't you build a composite index on these 2 fields?

Comment: Did you tried these queries without the ORDER BY?

Comment: @Shadow & _jrdi I've added your suggestions as an "Update" in the question

Comment: @fguillen in that case, I would try to create an index like (is_mongo_synced, id, completed_at) or even (id, is_mongo_synced, completed_at)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your questions are quite complicated.  But, your for your first query:

```
select completions.* 
from completions  
where completed_at is not null and
      completions.is_mongo_synced = 0 
order by completions.id asc
limit 10;
```

The best index in on `(is_mongo_synced, completed_at)`.  There might be other ways to write the query, but in the index you are forcing, the columns are not in an optimal order.

The difference in performance in your second query is probably because the data is actually being sorted.  A few extra hundreds of thousands of rows can affect the sort time.  The dependence on the value of `id` is probably way the index is not used.  If you changed the index to `(is_mongo_synced, id, completed_at)`, then index usage would be more likely.

MySQL has good documentation on composite indexes.  You might want to review it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

#### After adding the suggested filter

After adding the index:

```
KEY `index_completions_on_is_mongo_synced_and_id_and_completed_at` (`is_mongo_synced`,`id`,`completed_at`) USING BTREE,
```

And executing the long query again

```
select completions.* 
from completions  
where 
  (completed_at is not null) 
  and completions.is_mongo_synced = 0 
  order by completions.id asc limit 10;
```

It takes **156ms**, which is very good.

Checking the `explain extended` we see MySQL is using the correct index:

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: completions
type: ref
possible_keys: index_completions_on_completed_at_and_is_mongo_synced_and_id,index_completions_on_is_mongo_synced_and_id_and_completed_at
key: index_completions_on_is_mongo_synced_and_id_and_completed_at
key_len: 2
ref: const
rows: 1626322
filtered: 100
Extra: Using index condition; Using where
```

Comment: I'm afraid that is_mongo_synced is not selective enough. I would probably leave that out of the composite index.

Comment: I'm reviewing the [documentation you mention](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) and still I don't understand why `(is_mongo_synced, completed_at)` is better than my one `(completed_at, is_mongo_synced, id)`. As far `is_mongo_synced, completed_at` are on the top left part of the index I suppose I can use this index to filter by these two fields.

Comment: @fguillen . . . `completed_at` has an inequality in the `where` clause.  When it is the first key in the index, no other columns in the index will get used.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to force index

```
(completed_at, is_mongo_synced, id)
```

It's a b-tree and it has to first explore all the distinct values of `completed_at` that are not `NULL`, then the correct mongo_synced at for each of them, them collect all the IDs and sort them and finally visit the table to fetch the desired rows.

With the primary key on the other hand it (assuming it's the clustering key) it just jumps fetches the page that has completions.id > 2000000 and reads consecutive rows until it gathers 10 of them, if not on this page then the next one is fetched.

In the end both queries probably check similar number of pages in the table + the first one has to fetch the entire index and sort it.

If you want to use an index try

```
(is_mongo_synced, id, completed_at)
```

Please consult the manual on [clustered indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html).

Comment: I accepted the @gordon-linoff answer just because it had more _positives_, but you both suggested the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

Caveat:  I am assuming InnoDB.

To build the optimal index,

1. Collect all the '=' values.  This is *only* `is_mongo_synced`.  This gets the lookup looking in one contiguous spot in the index.
2. Add on *one* more thing.

If you add `completed_at`, it will scan through all the non-NULL entries, gathering the `ids` for subsequent sorting.  The sorting (`ORDER BY`) costs something, and cannot be avoided with `INDEX(is_mongo_synced, completed_at, ...)`.

If, instead, you add `id`, now there is a chance that it can avoid the sort.  But it still has to finish filtering (to avoid NULL `completed_at` rows).  So, `INDEX(is_mongo_synced, id, ...)` *may* be good.

If you have both indexes, the optimizer is not good at picking between those two indexes because it depends heavily on the distribution of the data and whether you also have a `LIMIT`.  You, who understand the data, may *or may not* be able to correctly pick which index will be better.

I said "...".  I meant that you could stop there, or you could add more columns to the index.  Adding more columns gets into what is called a "covering index".  If *all* the columns mentioned in the `SELECT` exist (anywhere) in a secondary index, then it is "covering".  So?  First, let me back up...

When looking up something in a *secondary* index, it finds the `PRIMARY KEY` at the bottom of the BTree.  Then it looks up the other column(s) by drilling down the clustered PK's BTree.  This extra drilldown can be costly.  But...

If the index is "covering", then there is no need to do that extra BTree drill-down.

You accidentally had a "covering" index, but not in the optimal order.  The *entire* index needed to be scanned, followed by a sort.  Each of my indexes avoids scanning the entire index, thereby is likely to be faster.

By adding extra column, I have two (competing) covering indexes:

```
KEY mci (is_mongo_synced, completed_at, id)
KEY mic (is_mongo_synced, id, completed_at)
```

An aside... Since the PK is automatically added to each secondary key, those 3-column indexes exist even if I mentioned only the first 2 columns.  So, don't be puzzled if you try 2 and 3 but find no difference.

For clarity, I will leave 'mci' and 'mic' with 3 explicit columns.

Re-analyzing them...

'mci' will scan the part of the index containing `is_mongo_synced=0 AND completed_at IS NOT NULL`.  These 'rows' in the index are consecutive, thereby minimizing disk hits.  And it gets the ids, which are then sorted.

'mic' will scan the part of the index containing `is_mongo_synced=0`.  This is a bigger part than for 'mci'.  But the ids are in order, thereby eliminating the sort.  Still, it must now scratch off the NULL rows as it scans through the index.

Bottom line.  I would replace your composite index ('cmi') with both 'mic' and 'mci'.

If you have other queries, such as one that looks at specific completed date(s), you might still need an index starting with `completed_at`.

See also my index cookbook: [mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

One more thing...  If all the data and/or index blocks that you need are in cache (the "buffer pool"), the query will run perhaps 10 times as fast as if you are hitting the disk.  See `innodb_buffer_pool_size` for tuning that cache -- usually 70% of *available* memory is good.  Your 9 minute test smells like the buffer pool was either cold or too small.

Comment: Regarding to the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` I'm using a RDS instance `db.m3.large` with `7.5GB` ram. And in the set up I see `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3/4 of the ram`, meaning `~5.6GB`. I'm gonna upgrade this instance when I see a good moment.